# PowerBI - Format Date in DatePicker slicer as dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: powerbi, date-formatting

I have a PBI report which has a date slicer, and I have the date format set to dd/mm/yyyy as I'm in the UK and this works fine in PBI Desktop.

However, when I publish this report, the format displays as mm/dd/yyyy as per the American format.

Desktop
[image]

Published
[image]

Does anyone know how to get the published report to show the date in the correct format?

PS. In my defence, I didn't pick the colours for the slicers.

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot.

Comment: Screenshots added

Comment: Can you please open report in IE browser once and let us know how it shows?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the user's settings in Power BI Service. Check what is set in [Language settings](https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/settings/general/language):

[image]

Comment: As I understood, it will set only language. How does it sets Date & Time?

Comment: It also affects culture info, including date formats (if not explicitly set in the report, which doesn't look the be the case here).

Comment: ok, Even I tried this option but didn't solve the issue.. I have also refer https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-apply-UK-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-in-Date-slicer/td-p/599712 still same issue..

Comment: Check the date format of the column. Note the tooltip, that says _"Date formats that begin with an asterisk (*) respond to changes in regional date and time settings that are specified for the operating system."_.

Comment: I have set date everywhere with dd-mm-yyyy format. But still retains same result.. I have downloaded Nov-2019 PBI desktop and set custom date to dd-mm-yyyy in model but no success.

Comment: I have attached both view in below image screenshot FYR,
Desktop view - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cbis.png
PBI Service view - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvozs.png

Comment: The slicer has it's own opinion about the date format. But it still depends on the language in settings. For example, date format in Desktop is `dd.MM.yyyy` and I see `13.01.2019` in table and `13.1.2019 г.` in slicer (Bulgarian format) there, but by default is shown as `13.01.2019` and `1/13/2019` in the service. However, when I set the language to Bulgarian, I see `13.01.2019` and `13.1.2019 г.` (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToTdd.png) The language settings of the browser matters. For IE these are Windows settings, but browsers like Chrome has their own.

Comment: Setting to English doesn't really help me as both the UK and US are English. The language settings don't differentiate between these, and my date formats are all set to the correct format for the UK.

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for your explanation., I can see date format in IE as dd-mm-yyyy and dd-mm-yyyy in chrome. But it looks browser default behavior nothing to do with settings since all of my other reports replicating same result without any additional settings...